# Why do multiple setState calls in an async function cause multiple renders?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The issue is summarized well [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-hooks-gotchas-setstate-in-async-effects-d2fd84b02305); basically, if you have an async function in useEffect (which is where you'd expect such functions), you cause a re-render of your component for every state that is updated. I generally don't want to be bunching up things as in the authors solution/workaround, and to me this behavior doesn't make sense (you'd expect all your state updates to happen together).

Is this by design? If so, is there a better way to deal with this, such that I can perform all my updates without having to worry about ordering, etc? This feels like a bug, but maybe just a flaw in my understanding.

Code for reference:

```
export default function App (): JSX.Element {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setPending(true)
    fetchUser().then((fetchedUser) => {
      setPending(false)
      setUser(fetchedUser) // This updated value won't initially be seen by other effects dependant on 'pending'
    })
  }, [])
  // …
}
```

Comment: Also the new [concurrent mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-adoption.html) batches all synchronous updates by default, without a wrapper function.

Comment: Huh, for some reason I thought it wouldn't let me answer my own question until after 24 hours; maybe remembering wrong, or StackOverflow changed. Thanks for the extra reference as well.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up figuring this out; see [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259). You need to manually batch things currently, with `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => { ... })`. Despite the name, it is seemingly widely regarded as quite stable.

It is also corrected in the currently in-development [Concurrent Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-adoption.html) for React.